# Spring aop @annotation pointcut with xml config

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

Can I use `@annotation` to define a pointcut using Spring xml-based configuration, or does it only work when I define the pointcuts using annotations?
Should this work?

```
<aop:pointcut id="inPreparedStatementLoggingMethod" expression="@annotation(com.blah.dao.LogPreparedStatement)"/>
```

The annotated methods are in an abstract Spring bean. Can I advise methods in an *abstract* Spring bean?

```
<bean id="baseSqlDao" class="com.blah.dao.BaseSqlDao" abstract="true">
  <description>Abstract super-class for most of the database access objects</description>
  <property name="sqlMapClient" ref="sqlMapClient"/>
</bean>
```

I have some other pointcuts and aspects that are working, but it never hits the breakpoint in this aspect's method.

```
<aop:aspect id="preparedStatementLoggingAspect" ref="methodProfileAspect">
  <aop:around method="doPreparedStatementLogging" pointcut-ref="inPreparedStatementLoggingMethod"/>
</aop:aspect>
```

Even when I give up on only advising the annotated methods, and try advising all the methods in that abstract Spring bean, it still doesn't hit the breakpoint. This makes me suspect that it won't work with abstract beans, because I have other similarly defined pointcuts that do work.

```
<aop:pointcut id="inBaseSqlDaoMethod" expression="within(com.blah.dao.BaseSqlDao)"/>
<aop:aspect id="preparedStatementLoggingAspect" ref="methodProfileAspect">
  <aop:around  method="doPreparedStatementLogging"  pointcut-ref="inBaseSqlDaoMethod"/>
</aop:aspect>
```

I can't find any errors in the logs. Are there any logging categories in Spring or AspectJ that I should switch to debug level to investigate this further?

Comment: Are the annotated target methods overridden in a concrete subclass? I am asking for a specific reason.

Comment: No, they are not overridden, @kriegaex. The implementations are all in the abstract bean, but none of them are `final`.

Comment: Okay, then the problem is not the typical error that people expect method annotations from interfaces or base classes to be inherited by implementing classes or subclasses, which would have been a false assumption. In this case I ask you to either just try if it works with annotation-style aspect syntax in order to answer the question by yourself or to post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so as to enable your helpers here to reproduce your problem. I do not feel inclined to invent a full sample by myself.

Comment: Thanks, @kriegaex. In writing a MCVE, I have realised the cause of my problem. The advised methods in the super class are being called from methods in the concrete class. When Spring bean calls one of it's own methods, that method will not be advised. I should not extend the abstract bean, but instead it should be a dependency of the concrete beans.

Comment: Of course, calls via `this.myMethod(..)` will not work in a proxy-based framework such as Spring AOP. You would have to switch to AspectJ (can be used in Spring via LTW, which is nicely documented) if this was a must-have requirement. P.S.: The beauty of creating an MCVE is that often you understand the problem better when isolating it. I have seen many cases here on SO when people realised what was wrong by themselves when preparing the MCVE I asked for. ;-)